# ¿Cómo decir el numero mayor y menor que se digitó? JAVA

Tags: java

cómo puedo decir el numero mayor y menor que se digite.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner empleados = new Scanner(System.in);
            int Sueldos;
            int suma = 0;
            int promedio = 0;

            System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados:");
            Sueldos = empleados.nextInt(); //Obtenemos la cantidad de empleados

            for (int i = 1; i <= Sueldos; i++) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el sueldo del empleado" + " " + i + " " + "de" + " " + Sueldos + ":");
                int nota = empleados.nextInt();
                suma = suma + nota; //Sumamos para luego promediar
            }
            promedio = suma / Sueldos; //Realizamos el respectivo promedio de sueldos
            System.out.println("El promedio de los sueldos es de:" + promedio);

        }


    }
```

Comment: te refieres a una función?

Comment: ¿Entiendo que lo que quieres es una clase para construir un objeto a partir de esta?

Comment: Sí, me refiero a una función para realizar la en una clase y hacer llamados en la clase principal @NicolasOñate

Comment: Sí, @Aritzbn así es.

Comment: O cómo decir el sueldo menor y mayor que se digitó en el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es hacer algo como esto:

Clase Empresa: Es la encargada de manejar lo referente a una empresa como los empleados y sus sueldos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Empresa {

    private float[] empleados;

    public Empresa(int cantidadEmpleados) {
        empleados = new float[cantidadEmpleados];
    }

    public float[] getEmpleados() {
        return empleados;
    }

    public void setEmpleados(float[] empleados) {
        this.empleados = empleados;
    }

    public void asignarSueldos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el sueldo del empleado" + " " + (i + 1) + " de " + empleados.length + ":");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            empleados[i] = sc.nextFloat();
        }
    }

    public double obtenerPromedioSueldos() {
        double suma = 0;
        for (float empleado : empleados) {
            suma += empleado;
        }
        return suma / empleados.length;
    }

    public float mayorSueldo() {
        float mayor = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        for (float empleado : empleados) {
            if(mayor < empleado){
                mayor = empleado;
            }
        }
        return mayor;
    }

    public float menorSueldo() {
        float menor = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        for (float empleado : empleados) {
            if(menor > empleado){
                menor = empleado;
            }
        }
        return menor;
    }
}
```

Clase Main: Es la clase principal de donde se llama a la clase Empresa.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        Empresa e = new Empresa(n);
        e.asignarSueldos();
        System.out.println("El promedio de sueldos es de: " + e.obtenerPromedioSueldos());
        System.out.println("El mayor sueldo es de: " + e.mayorSueldo());
        System.out.println("El menor sueldo es de: " + e.menorSueldo());

    }
}
```

Comment: Esto es muy poco escalable. Mejor utilizar un List (en vez de arrays) y usar `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) `una vez asignas los sueldos

Comment: Hola @JDev el objetivo de su pregunta no viene dada a la forma en que guarda el salario de los empleados, el uso de array es solo para ilustrar mediante un ejemplo. No obstante en caso de usar un List no usaria el `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`, ya que estoy usando un algoritmo que se ejecuta en O(n). Saludos.

Comment: El `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` para el mejor caso tiene una complejidad temporal de O(n * log n).

Comment: Es mucho mas trivial y simpre directamente guardar una variable con el mayor y menor sueldo, y comparalos en cada ingreso. Y seguro esa era la idea del ejercicio. en Java se usan float para montos en monedas?

Comment: float puede darte problemas de presición

Comment: Es cierto que float para algunos casos da problemas de presición, pero como es para guardar el sueldo que como máximo tiene dos lugares después de la coma no nos dará problemas.